# Verifying an algebra

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider the metric space of bounded, continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and a subset $E$:

\begin{equation}
E=\left\{\sum_{i=0}^N a_ie^{b_ix}\mid a_i,b_i\in\mathbb{R}\right\}
\end{equation}

As part of showing that $E$ is an algebra, I want to prove that, for any $a_i,b_i,c_i,d_i\in\mathbb{R}$, it holds that:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^N a_ie^{b_ix}+\sum_{j=0}^M c_je^{d_jx}\in E
\end{equation}

However, I'm unable to find a way to combine these two summations and write them in the form of a single linear combination. Ideally, letting the constants equal $0$ if necessary, I'd like to claim that the two sums above are equal to:

\begin{equation}
\sum_{k=0}^{\max(M,N)} (a_k+c_k)(e^{b_kx}+e^{d_kx})
\end{equation}

But this is false. Any ideas?